# Django Admin Inline duplicated queries

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

In my Admin page I have Order model with TabularInline of OrderItem model

```
class OrderItemStackAdmin(admin.TabularInline):
   model = OrderItem
   extra = 0
   fieldsets = (
    (_('Product'), {
        'fields': ('product', 'variant')
    }), (_('Add-Ons'), {
        'fields': ('product_add_ons', 'add_ons_note')
    }), (_('Price'), {
        'fields': ('quantity', 'product_price', 'add_ons_total_price')
    }), (_('Discount'), {
        'fields': ('discount',)
    })

   )

   def get_queryset(self, request):
      qs = super().get_queryset(request)
      return qs.select_related(
        "customer_order",
        "product",
        "variant"
    ).prefetch_related('product_add_ons')
```

Three foreign keys: **1.Order** **2.Product** **3.Variant**

One ManyToMany: **product_add_ons**

With select_related/prefetch related, only **19 queries reduced**, however, **35 duplicate/similar queries are found**.

[image: Screenshot]

Please note the below facts:

1. **ALL** duplicated queries share

> **NO SCROLL CURSOR WITH HOLD FOR SELECT**

2. Removing the inline removes all duplicated queries.
3. Removing any FK or ManyToMany also greatly reduce duplicated queries
4. Removing select_related/prefetch_related will result in

> ***70 queries including 55 similar and 35 duplicates***

Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 2):

Ok after many searches and several fail tries.

I finally managed to remove all duplicated/similar queries by **using Model form and adding it to admin inline**

```
class OrderItemForm(forms.ModelForm):
   """ OrderItem Model Form """
   products_choices = [('', '---------')]
   for item in Product.objects.values('pk', 'name', 'arabic_name'):
       products_choices.append(
        (item['pk'], f"{item['arabic_name']}-{item['name']}"))
   product = forms.ChoiceField(required=True,
                            choices=products_choices)

   variants_choices = [('', '---------')]
   variants_choices.extend(Variants.objects.values_list('pk', 'name'))
   variant = forms.ChoiceField(required=False,
                            choices=variants_choices)

class OrderItemStackAdmin(admin.TabularInline):
    """ Stacked Order Items """
    model = OrderItem
    form = OrderItemForm
    autocomplete_fields = ['product_add_ons']
    extra = 0
    fieldsets = (
    (_('Product'), {
        'fields': ('product', 'variant')
       }), (_('Add-Ons'), {
        'fields': ('product_add_ons', 'add_ons_note')
       }), (_('Price'), {
        'fields': ('quantity', 'product_price', 'add_ons_total_price')
      }), (_('Discount'), {
        'fields': ('discount',)
      })
    )

    def get_queryset(self, request):
       qs = super().get_queryset(request)
       return qs.prefetch_related('product_add_ons')
```

Comment: I think `extra = 0` is enough, no?

Comment: After many searches and failing trials this seems to be the only solution. Thanks.

Comment: @marke Unfortunately extra=0 wouldnt solve the issue case there more than filled inlines.

Comment: doesn't that lead to a bug? what happens when somebody adds a variant instance, and the server is not reset in a meantime? OrderItemForm will not be evaluated again and there will be no new option, no?

Comment: You are correct. Variant wont exists if it was created in same server instance.